# How to stop user moving to next step until finish the current step using Angular Material Stepper(Angular 4)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am using Angular Material to build my steppers and I want user to move step by step which means user has to finish the current step so that can move to the next step, however during searching the Angular Material Docs and CDK Docs I only found one related field property called 'editable' but that is used for stopping user return to previous steps, what property should I set to make stop user view the later steps and move one by one?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "complete"? Filling a form?

Comment: Right, "complete" from my side means filling the current form.  I also set some validators if all the fields are filled and all the validators are passed then when user click 'next' button, it is complete and can go to the next step :) @Jota.Toledo

Comment: there are examples int the docs of what you are looking for, please check them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `[linear]="isLinear"` to stepper like this `<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true">`